# Unicode characters in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, unicode

I have the following PowerShell code:

```
$Content = python posh-unicode.py
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("posh-unicode.txt", $Content)
```

posh-unicode.py is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

unicodestr = "테스트"

print(unicodestr)

with open('posh-unicode-py.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(unicodestr)
```

Unfortunately the characters written in `posh-unicode.txt` are corrupted, as characters shown with `Write-Host $Content`.

When I write into `posh-unicode-py.txt` directly from Python, characters are fine, so I suspect it is PowerShell's problem. How do I fix this? Maybe the way I call the Python script is wrong?

FYI, I'm using Windows 8.1 and PowerShell v4.0.

Answer (score 0):

No one except you knows what exactly your python script created. This makes it hard to help you.
Try specifying what detailed encoding you may need. e.g.

```
$filecontent = cat $myfile
$Utf8NoBom = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($False)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($myfile, $fileContent, $Utf8NoBom)
```

This tried to convert $myfile to UTF8 without BOM.

ref. [MSDN, .net Encoding Class - System.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the problem is not from writing part, but from the reading output from the python script part.